# Google Chrome's back button doesn't redirect

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have created an internal back button which redirects the user to the page which they were at previously. However, when the user performs a click action on the browser back button it redirects to the "New Tab" page built into Google Chrome rather than redirecting the user to the previous page. How would one repair this issue?

Button Element:

```
<input type="button" id="btnback" class="btn btn-blue btn-xs pull-left" value="Back" onclick="onClickBack()" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function onClickBack() { 
    window.location.replace("frontscreensnomedload.jsp"); 
}
```

Comment: To get answers, show us the JavaScript code that redirects to the previous page. I also suspect this is some kind of (missing) `history.push()` issue.

Comment: <input type="button" id="btnback" class="btn btn-blue btn-xs pull-left" value="Back" onclick="onClickBack()" />

Comment: Please add the code to your question in the future, and more importantly, add the `onClickBack` function... that's the one we need to see. And since this is a "back" button, you should also tell us how your website's navigation works in general. I.e. what does the user do to get to the page with the back button, and what's the code used.

Comment: this back button takes me to frontscreensnomedload.jsp but chrome back button doesnt!!.

Comment: how can i make google chrome's back button take me to the previous page which is frontscreensnomedload.jsp

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace (first paragraph)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you want the navigation to be recorded in the history, or Google Chrome can't "figure out" where to go. To solve this simply use `location.assign();` , meaning your code should look like this:

```
function onClickBack() { 
    window.location.assign("frontscreensnomedload.jsp"); 
}
```

This code will record the change in the browser history.

In addition I recommend simplifying your code like this:

```
<input type="button" id="btnback" class="btn btn-blue btn-xs pull-left" value="Back" onclick="window.location.assign("frontscreensnomedload.jsp")" />
```

Your function is only one line, so it means that it is much more efficient to simply declare it in the button.